# Find out home directory of running Oracle instance

Tags: process, directory, oracle-database

There are two oracle directories on our system:

- oracle
- oraclex

How can I find out which of them is used by the running Oracle instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to find it out. Some of them:

1) The easiest is to find out with which user the database process are running, then watch if this user has some environment variables set:

```
$ ps aux | grep ora_pmon
orauser    2653  (...)  ora_pmon_DB

$ su - orauser -c "echo \$ORACLE_HOME"
/u21/oracle/product
```

2) You may also have an `/etc/oratab`. If the databases are started automatically on boot, this file may contain the `$ORACLE_HOME`.

3) You can pick one oracle process and find out its environment:

```
$ ps aux | grep ora_pmon
orauser    2653  (...)  ora_pmon_DB

$ strings /proc/2653/environ | grep ORACLE_HOME
/u21/oracle/product
```

Note that `/proc/2653/environ` has a specific delimiter (shown as `^@`)

4) If you have an access to the database, using `sqlplus`, you can try this trick:

```
SQL> @?/foobar.foo
```

WATCHOUT!`foobar.foo` **should not exist**, so you will have an error message like `/u21/oracle/product/foobar.sql doesn't exist`